# Linear lnterpolation using awk

Tags: awk

I have a data file with following format:

```
1  3  2  3  5
2  3  2  4  3
3  3  2  2  4
4  3  2  2  -6
5  3  2  2  -4
```

I would like to linearly interpolate the columns into 4 more points. e.g.

The output of the 1st column will look like

```
1
i1
i2
i3
i4
2
i1
i2
i3
i4
3
i1
i2
i3
i4
4
i1
i2
i3
i4
5
```

My below script is working very well for each column.

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '{
    y2 = $1
    if (NR > 1) {
        steps = NR - prev_line_nr
        step_size = (y2 - y1) / (5 * steps)
        for (i = 1; i < 5 * steps; i++) {
            interpolated_value = y1 + i * step_size
            print interpolated_value
        }
    }

    prev_line_nr = NR
    print y2
    y1 = y2
}' input_file
```

But I can't able to modify the script for all columns. My script is as below:

```
awk '{
    for (j = 1; j < 5 * steps; j++) {
     y2=$j
         if (NR > 1) {
        steps = NR - prev_line_nr
        step_size = (y2 - y1) / 5 * steps)
        for (i = 1; i < 5 * steps; i++) {
            interpolated_value = y1 + i * step_size
            print interpolated_value
        }
    }

    prev_line_nr = NR
    print y2
    y1 = y2
}
}' input_file
```

Desire output:

```
1       3       2       3       5
1.2     3       2       3.2     4.6
1.4     3       2       3.4     4.2
1.6     3       2       3.6     3.8
1.8     3       2       3.8     3.4
2       3       2       4       3
2.2     3       2       3.6     3.2
2.4     3       2       3.2     3.4
2.6     3       2       2.8     3.6
2.8     3       2       2.4     3.8
3       3       2       2       4
3.2     3       2       2       2
3.4     3       2       2       0
3.6     3       2       2       -2
3.8     3       2       2       -4
4       3       2       2       -6
4.2     3       2       2       -5.6
4.4     3       2       2       -5.2
4.6     3       2       2       -4.8
4.8     3       2       2       -4.4
5       3       2       2       -4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR>1 {
        # store step size for each column
        for (col = 1; col <= NF; col++)
            step[col] = ($col - prev[col]) / numsteps

        for (n = 1; n < numsteps; n++) {

            # unroll loop slightly to avoid OFS/ORS tests
            row = ( prev[1] + n*step[1] )

            # calculate remaining interpolated columns
            for (col = 2; col <= NF; col++)
                row = row OFS ( prev[col] + n*step[col] )

            print row
        }
    }
    {
        # save current line to use when processing next line
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
            prev[i] = $i

        # print current line after updating OFS
        $1=$1
        print
    }
' OFS='\t' numsteps=5 input_file
```

Comment: It works well. Nice and clever answer!

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Would you please update it if I want to print up to 3 decimal points for the column 4 and 5.

Comment: you could set `CONVFMT` (eg. `'%.3g'`), either globally or by testing the column number before each assignment. Or using `sprintf` on the appropriate `step[col]` assignments could work too.

Comment: @jhnc : would it be simpler to just `split($0, prev)` instead of looping through them one by one ? The return value from this `split()` should be same as `NF`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -e 'old_table=$<.read.split(/\R/).map(&:split).map{|sa| sa.map(&:to_f)}.transpose
steps=5
new_table=[]
old_table.each{|sa| row=[sa[ 0]]
    (0...sa.length-1).each{|e| v0,v1=sa[e..e+1]; t=(v1-v0)/steps
        row << (1...steps).inject([]){|acc,e| acc<<(v0+t*e)}+[v1]
    }
    new_table << row.flatten
}
puts new_table.transpose.map{|sa| sa.join("\t")}
' file | column -t
```

Prints:

```
1.0 3.0 2.0 3.0 5.0
1.2 3.0 2.0 3.2 4.6
1.4 3.0 2.0 3.4 4.2
1.6 3.0 2.0 3.6 3.8
1.8 3.0 2.0 3.8 3.4
2.0 3.0 2.0 4.0 3.0
2.2 3.0 2.0 3.6 3.2
2.4 3.0 2.0 3.2 3.4
2.6 3.0 2.0 2.8 3.6
2.8 3.0 2.0 2.4 3.8
3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 4.0
3.2 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0
3.4 3.0 2.0 2.0 0.0
3.6 3.0 2.0 2.0 -2.0
3.8 3.0 2.0 2.0 -4.0
4.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 -6.0
4.2 3.0 2.0 2.0 -5.6
4.4 3.0 2.0 2.0 -5.2
4.6 3.0 2.0 2.0 -4.8
4.8 3.0 2.0 2.0 -4.4
5.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 -4.0
```

Or, this awk:

```
awk '{lines[FNR]=$0}
END{
    for(i=1;i<FNR; i++) {
        cnt=split(lines[i], fst)
        split(lines[i+1], nxt)
        for(e=0; e<steps; e++) {
            for(j=1;j<=cnt;j++) {
                v0=fst[j]; v1=nxt[j]
                t=(v1-v0)/steps
                printf "%s%s",v0+t*e,(j<cnt ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
    print lines[FNR]
}' steps=5 OFS="\t" file | column -t
```

Prints:

```
1    3  2  3    5
1.2  3  2  3.2  4.6
1.4  3  2  3.4  4.2
1.6  3  2  3.6  3.8
1.8  3  2  3.8  3.4
2    3  2  4    3
2.2  3  2  3.6  3.2
2.4  3  2  3.2  3.4
2.6  3  2  2.8  3.6
2.8  3  2  2.4  3.8
3    3  2  2    4
3.2  3  2  2    2
3.4  3  2  2    0
3.6  3  2  2    -2
3.8  3  2  2    -4
4    3  2  2    -6
4.2  3  2  2    -5.6
4.4  3  2  2    -5.2
4.6  3  2  2    -4.8
4.8  3  2  2    -4.4
5    3  2  2    -4
```